# jQuery jump to element after resorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm using a cute little script to jump to an element by clicking on it.

```
$('.image-only').click(function () {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('scale-image');
      $(".grid-item").not($(this).parent()).removeClass('scale-image');
      $grid.isotope('layout');
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 100
      }, 400);
});
```

The script works quite fine with one single issue. I'm using the Isotope Grid System for ordering/sorting the images. If the user click on an item, the image scales up (`$(this).parent().toggleClass('scale-image');`) and the grid is resorting (`$grid.isotope('layout');`). **The jQuery moves the viewport to the old position of the element, so it's not correct.**

[Have a look here](http://relaunch.headonline.de/projekte/is-leuchten-planungs-und-beratungsordner/)! (click on one of the images below)

Is there a way to correct it?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to play around without a snippet/fiddle, but have you tried adding a small timeout before scrolling? It could be that isotope updates the position of the element with a slight delay. Make a function out of your scrolling code and try 'setTimeout(yourScrollingFunction, 200)'. See if that helps.

Comment: Try to add `setTimeout` before the scrolling.

Comment: Nothing happens now. The scrolling is not working as well. I'm usind this code: `$('.image-only').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 100
        }, 400);
    }, 3000);
});` I've updated the site.